# how can you integrate GoSquared analytics with Telescope

Tags: javascript, meteor, analytics, telescope

I've set up a basic telescope server. All is working very nicely. I'd like to integrate with my GoSquared analytics, but all attempts have failed the "Check Integration" step of GoSquared.

What I've tried:
I've tried adding the script to both the Footer Code and Extra Code sections of the Telescope settings. Neither passed GoSquared's test. Since the code is compressed/mangled it's tough to tell if it even gets injected at all or what the problem might be.

I've also tried setting the Meteor setting "goSquaredId" to my ID. I think Meteor has support for this even though it's not in the Telescope settings. But this did not work either.

I've attempted doing some of my own tests with other code, but the giant block of opaque mangled JS that Meteor produces definitely makes it a challenge. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Is this an issue verifying that GoSquared is being loaded into the compiled page? Are you following the documentation on how to inject code into 'views'? Have you followed the [Hooks](http://www.telescopeapp.org/docs/customizing/hooks/) portion of the documentation? Can you hook the customization into the `footerModules` array?

Comment: i've verified that the code was at least loaded. however the compiled nature of meteor makes it challenging to do much else.

Comment: i'm not familiar with the documentation to which you refer, is that part of Telescope?Do you have a link or a reference point that might get me started?

Comment: There is a hyperlink to the documentation I am referring to in my earlier comment. Telescope will let you turn debug mode on from the UI which could provide more information on any loading issues or reference problems.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  I did eventually find the hook documentation.  And then moved on to attempt to create a package.  However this all seems to rely on learning the entire Meteor way of doing things. I'm afraid I don't have the time to learn an entire framework, just to get analytics to work.  ;-)

Comment: If there does exist a more complete solution other than "build your own meteor package" I'd still be interested. However, I just don't have time for the Meteor learning curve at the moment. Maybe next year.